# Modify the data found between two recurring patterns in a multi-line string

Tags: python, regex

I have a multi-line string, it's around to 10000-40000 characters(changes as per the data returned by an API). In this string, there are a number of tables (they are a part of the string, but formatted in a way that makes them look like a table). The tables are always in a repeating pattern. The pattern looks like this:

`==============================================================================`

`*THE HEADINGS/COLUMN NAMES IN THE TABLE*`

`------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`THE DATA IN THE TABLE, FORMATTED TO BE UNDER RESPECTIVE COLUMNS`

I'm trying to display the contents in html on a locally hosted webpage, and I want to have the heading of the tables displayed in a specific way (think color, font size). For that, I'm using the python regex module to identify the pattern, but I'm failing to do so due to inexperience in using the `re` module. To modify the part that I need modified, I'm using the below piece of code:

`re.sub(r'\={78}.*\-{78}',some_replacement_string, complete_multi_line_string)`

But the above piece of code is not giving me the output I require, since it is not matching the pattern properly(I'm sure the mistake is in the pattern I'm asking re.sub to match)

However:

`re.sub(r'\-{78}',some_replacement_string, complete_multi_line_string)`

is working as it's returning the string with the replacement, but the slight problem here is that there are multiple `------------------------------------------------------------------------------`s in the code that I do not want modified. Please help me out here. If it is helpful, the output that I'm wanting is something like:

`==============================================================================`

`<span>*THE HEADINGS/COLUMN NAMES IN THE TABLE*<\span>`

`------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`THE DATA IN THE TABLE, FORMATTED TO BE UNDER RESPECTIVE COLUMNS`

Also, please note that there are newlines or `\n`s after the `==============================================================================`s, the `<span>*THE HEADINGS/COLUMN NAMES IN THE TABLE*<\span>`s and the `------------------------------------------------------------------------------`s, if that is helpful in getting to the solution.

The code snippet I'm currently trying to debug, if helpful:

`result = re.sub(r'\={78}.*\-{78}', replacement, multi_line_string)`
`l = result.count('<\span>')`
`print(l)`

PS: There are 78 `=` and 78 `-` in all the occurances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the following version:

```py
re.sub(r'(={78})\n(.*?)\n(-{78})', r'\1<span>\2</span>\3', complete_multi_line_string, flags=re.S)
```

The changes I made here include:

- Match on lazy dot `.*?` instead of greedy dot `.*`, to ensure that we don't match across header sections
- Match with the `re.S` flag, so that `.*?` will match across newlines

Comment: It's partially working. The table is being detected now (I have 5 tables in the test snippet and it's detecting 5). The problem is everything before the 78 `-` is getting replaced by the replacement string. The multi-line data consists of a lot of data before and after the tables, so it's important that it not get modified. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try the updated version.

Comment: I did try the updated version, and it's actually closer than the first solution. Is there a way to specify that the line with the column headers are in one line only? The current solution is adding <span> in a few places where there are 78 '='s much above the pattern, so it's taking the 78 `=`s, then the 50 or so lines of data, then the 78 `-`s and making them between the <span> tags.

Comment: This is the best I can do without knowing your actual data.  The answer works for what you did post above.

Comment: All right, this has actually been helpful. Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is, instead of matching just `.*?` inside the tags, you need to be more specific and instead put `(...)` around only what you want.  Use the same replacement.